# Why wrapped radio buttons are selected by default in Vue?

Tags: html, vue.js

When I create a radio button with plain HTML, it's not selected by default:

```html
<input type="radio"> Radio
```

However, if I try to create a wrapper component for the native Radio Button in Vue, like this (see [Vue playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNqFUkFOwzAQ/IrlC0Uq6aG3klaiqAeQgKogLphDlGyKS2Jb9roUVfk7a4eGqKrKKfHMeHe8s3t+Y0yy9cAnPHW5lQaZA/RmJpSsjbbI9hbKhpVW10xwUgp+3XGrrJB67hG1ahUXyaiHhcIXpBYq18ohq3UBFZsyqji4JDwdtS2pGR0QalNlCHRiLO2X3l7Fm1PB41dwNiJROurd4EOOjrqUcp1snFb0nn2oI3iuayMrsE8GJbkQfMIiE7isqvTXfcTQehge8PwD8s8T+MbtAib40oIDu6VhdBxmdg3Y0ovnR9jRf0eSb1+R+gy5AqcrHzy2srlXBdnu6aLbuzh5qdYvbrFDUO7wqGA0KJuoj1Hdnnn6n91xMo73hGpoikfxndgLxto0jdXGUZoFlFLBMpwGb9Q3q8KSvIeAD9IY22sgOv1DgP7dAqmMR4bfBih8G6xR+EfrEOsSPImdCY3Gkl8fs3ZJj9el+QEvfwNj)):

**RadioButton.vue**

```js
<script setup>
  const props = defineProps(["value"]);
  const modelValue = defineModel();
</script>

<template>
  <input type="radio" v-model="modelValue" :value="props.value"> Radio
</template>
```

and then use it the following way:

**App.vue**

```js
<script setup>
import {ref} from "vue";
import RadioButton from './RadioButton.vue';

const model = ref();
</script>

<template>
  <RadioButton v-model="model" />
</template>
```

Then I get the button preselected!

I can tell that the issue is gone as soon [as I pass the `value` prop](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNqFUk1PwzAM/StRLgxptEK7jW4SQzuABEwDcSEcqtYdGW0S5aMMTf3vOCktZZrGqbXfs/2c5z29ViqqHdApTUymubLEgHVqzgSvlNSW7DUUDSm0rAijyGT0qsfWac7lwlkrRcs4i+JBzjc+QzYTmRTGkkrmUJIZwY6jc8wncTsSh2FgoVJlagEjQpJh6/oiVM4YDV9GSZ2WDjC+xP8YC5J4UE3H1BqcWPBNtDVS4G5735PRTFaKl6AfleWoiNEpCYjH0rKUn3chZ7WDcZfP3iH7OJLfmp3PMbrSYEDX+DA9ZlO9AdvCy6cH2OF/D+IOrkT2CXANRpbOa2xpCydylD3gBbW3wQUuNs9mubMgTLeUF+qZTeAH225OrP4rdxJNQh0TDb7igZVHboSQ1lmlpTLobA4FF7Dy0egV53qbGH3zZnfUYOGLB3r+vU/9exFcKGeJ/VLeeO2l+UP4exqhL6an3YEEYdGPjnl7sIfn0nwDniMHCg==):

**App.vue**

```js
<RadioButton v-model="model" value="1" />
```

But why is that? Isn't that a bug? The native Radio Button is not checked if I don't pass it a value. Why is it in Vue?

Comment: It is because vue initializes the ```modelValue``` with the provided value, which makes it a valid value for the radio button, causing it to be checked. If no ```value``` is provided, ```modelValue``` is initialized with ```undefined```, which is not a valid value for a radio button, so it remains unchecked.

Comment: *If no value is provided, modelValue is initialized with undefined, which is not a valid value for a radio button, so it remains unchecked.* - when no `value` is provided, the radio button **is** checked. That's the point of my question.

Comment: What do you mean no value but radio button is checked?[see here](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: @KeyboardCorporation in your example change `const model = ""` to `const model = ref()` (which is equevalent to `const model = ref(undefined)`). The idea is to replicate the case when there's no initial value - no radio button is selected, and the user is required to make a selection.

Comment: You defined ```model``` using ```ref()``` without providing an initial value and means that vue will treat it as undefined. If there's no other logic setting the value of model, it should not cause the radio button to be checked initially.  So when you do ```const model = ref(null);``` it will unchecked the radio button.

Comment: v-model is really just [shorthand](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html#under-the-hood) for `:value="x" @input="y"`.  By assigning a v-model, you are implicitly binding to the value attribute, but if there is no native `value` attribute, then an undefined v-model is the same as selecting an undefined value attribute, hence the radio button becomes selected.

Comment: @yoduh you're wrong. It used to be `value` in Vue 2, and I'm talking Vue 3 here, where it is `modelValue` now. It's just that native inputs have some special treatment.

Comment: @KeyboardCorporation and yes, I do understand that `undefined === undefined`, and that's why the radio is checked initially. The thing is that the native radio button, even without the `value` attribute is *unchecked*. And that brings the confusion.

Comment: Vue 2 v-model expanded to `value` on both native elements and components.  Vue 3 it is `modelValue` on components but still `value` on native elements.  This must be true because `modelValue` has no meaning on native elements, v-model _must_ bind to `value` because that's where the "value" of the element is.

Comment: @yoduh *because that's where the "value" of the element is* - not necessarily. The "value" of checkboxes and radio buttons is the `checked` attribute.